# Increasing the size limit for /var/cache/apt/archives

Tags: debian, apt, cache

I have 2 systems running Debian at home and I am trying to minimize the bandwidth use while upgrading the packages. How can I increase the size limit of the cache, so that I could just copy the packages over LAN? (currently they get removed too quickly)

Comment: What is the output of `apt-config dump | grep -i clean`?

Comment: Hi @enzotib, I get nothing: `grzes:/home/ga# apt-config dump | grep -i clean?
grzes:/home/ga#`

Comment: The question mark was not part of the command :)

Comment: Heh :) Without the question mark I get the following: `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";`

Comment: It appears that `APT::Archives::MinAge` (default of 2) should be enough if you tend to do upgrades on both machines at similar times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size limit is controlled by the apt option `APT::Periodic::MaxSize`. You can display your current value using the following command:

```
apt-config dump | grep Periodic
```

To set the size, edit or create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99local-archive` and any of the following lines:

```
APT::Periodic::MaxSize "<size_in_MiB>";
APT::Periodic::MaxAge "<days>";
APT::Periodic::MinAge "<days>";
```

See `/etc/cron.daily/apt` for comments on available options, and the transition from `APT::Archives::*`.  (Ubuntu 14.04 ships `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive` which sets `APT::Archives::MaxSize`.  When they transition to `APT::Periodic` in that file, it will matter that you put your local changes in a file with a higher number.)

This sets the maximum size of the cache in MiB. If the cache
is bigger, cached package files are deleted until the size
requirement is met (the biggest packages will be deleted 
first).

Make sure to do this on all machines that mount the directory.

Comment: It's now `APT::Archives::MaxSize`, not `...Periodic...`.  (Ubuntu 14.04, apt `1.0.1ubuntu2.6`) There's also `...::MinAge` and `...::MaxAge` (in days, I guess since the defaults are 2 and 30).  I assume `MinAge` is a grace period for exceeding `MaxSize`.

Comment: Also note that if either machine does `apt-get autoclean`, any package that doesn't show up in **its** list as available will be removed. `

Comment: Also, Ubuntu ships `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive`, (dunno about Debian).  Files are processed in order, with later ones able to override earlier ones.  (I checked with `apt-config dump`.)  You should put your changed in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99local-archive`.

Comment: hmm, I wonder if you can set `Dir::Cache::archives` to an absolute path (like `/net/tesla/var/cache/apt/archives/`), instead of the default relative path (`archives/`).  Might be easier on a laptop that isn't always kept at home, easier than manually mounting over your local `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Comment: Oops, ignore my first comment.  https://lists.debian.org/deity/2014/03/msg00182.html and `/etc/cron.daily/apt` indicate that `APT::Periodic` is the new one, and `Archives` is the deprecated one.  I guess the cron job is the only thing to ever prune the cache, since the size/age stuff is now specific to it.

Comment: I prob. should have just made my own answer; I think I went too far with the suggested edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a separate caching proxy for your apt instances. [apt-proxy](http://apt-proxy.sourceforge.net/) is one tool you could try.  Let that do the caching and prune the individual apt archives more aggressively.

Comment: For just 2 machines?  Nah just NFS mount `/var/cache/apt/archives`, esp. now that Marco has identified the right setting to increase the max size.

Answer (score 1):

To set the cache size for apt, you need to edit `apt.conf`. You can get information on how to configure it in `man apt.conf`. If it is not already present create it in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or you may need to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` file, please refer specific version's documentation.

Debian provides `Cache-Limit` option in **APT Group** in `apt.conf`. You can experiment with it.

`man apt.conf` says,

```
Cache-Limit
              APT  uses  a  fixed  size  memory mapped cache file to store the
              'available' information. This sets the size of that cache.
```

So you need to put following line in `apt.conf`.

`APT::Cache-Limit "cache_size"` Put appropriate cache size in place.

Comment: `Cache-Limit` controls the cache in main memory used at runtime, not the disk cache in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: Yup, this answer is unfortunately wrong.  I guess grzenio accepted it without testing (since it's non-trivial to test.)