# Disk management issue

Tags: partition, kali-linux, disk-usage, cfdisk

After trying to execute the command `apt upgrade` from the terminal, I received the following error:

```
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

Not quite sure what to do about it. I also checked my disk storage to be safe, and everything is normal except my boot drive and loop0 directory, shown below:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1            0      0       0     - /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1
/dev/loop0      350450 350450       0  100% /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.sq
```

Currently trying to use `cfdisk` command to resize disk drives to compensate.

Comment: We won't be able to grow a live filesystem image in a DVD or pen.

Comment: @roaima I added the headers. apologies for the messiness

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be because of unused packages.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This will delete all packages not currently installed. If that doesn't free up enough space, then use

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will clear out all .debs downloaded and/or installed.

Or you can increase the size [limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22024/increasing-the-size-limit-for-var-cache-apt-archives).

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these accomplish the main goal of creating free space in the directory /var/cache/apt/archives/.

Comment: If you look closely at the OP fstab, while he does not say it, it is evident it is a live ISO image.